# Question regarding how increasing distance increases amplitude and intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A point source of light of amplitude $A_0$ gives rise to a particular light intensity when viewed at a distance from the source. When the amplitude is increased and the viewing distance is doubled, the light intensity is doubled. What is the new amplitude of the source?

The answer given is $2\sqrt2 A_0$ and I'm unsure how to get there. I know that:
$$I ∝ x^{-2}$$
and
$$I ∝ A^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the two proportional rules you say, we can write:

$$ I = k \frac{A^2}{x^2} $$

where $k$ is a constant.

In the second scenario that you describe:

$$ 2I = k \frac{A'^2}{(2x)^2} $$

isolating $A$ and $A'$ and dividing you obtain $A'/A=2\sqrt{2}$